# reduce vertical padding in as_flex_table

Tags: r, gtsummary

```
  as_flex_table_ex1 <-
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt,missing = "no") %>%
  add_p() %>%
  as_flex_table() %>% 
  valign(j = 1,valign = "center")


save_as_docx(as_flex_table_ex1,path = "1.docx")
```

Now - when I open the table in word, the padding between grade I,II and III is very "airy". How can I reduce this padding? I tried using the `padding(as_flex_table_ex1,padding.top=0,padding.bottom = 0,part="all")`, but I cant really see a difference in the rendered docx.

Answer (score 1):

So after a bit of research. This seems to do the trick.

```
as_flex_table_ex1 <-
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt,missing = "no") %>%
  add_p() %>%
  as_flex_table() %>% 
  valign(j = 1,valign = "center") 
as_flex_table_ex2 <- as_flex_table_ex1 %>% 
  hrule(rule = "exact") %>% 
  height(height=max(dim_pretty(.,part="body")$heights+0.3*max(dim_pretty(.,part="body")$heights)))



print(as_flex_table_ex2,preview="docx")
```

The dim_pretty factor multiplied by 0.3 is completely arbitrary. If someone is up to finding a legible height that automatically allows for different fonts and sizes it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue.  These are the commands I use to try to achieve a more compact table (much of what you've already tried). This is available in the function `gtsummary::theme_gtsummary_compact()`.

```r
x %>%
  flextable::fontsize(size = 8, part = "all") %>%
  flextable::padding(padding.top = 0, part = "all") %>%
  flextable::padding(padding.bottom = 0, part = "all")
```

I have had more success using a R Markdown Word templates, which helps direct the formatting in the Word doc.
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word-template.html